# How to change source code of page? using selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have source code of page like this:

```
<header style="position: fixed;">
```

When I use my script on java, I can't execute click action, because my element locate under the header. And I have an error:

> Element is not clickable at point (482, 10.116668701171875). Other element would receive the click...

I need to change source code of page to the next view:

```
<header style="position: absolute;">
```

Comment: Consider, please, this is bad practice for testing. You have to test product as it is

Comment: Yes, I know. I don't test the product. I do program for myself.

Comment: You can't change the source code of a page after the fact. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: I did it, like answer @Florent B. bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the style attribute on the first header tag:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style='position: absolute;'");
```

But a better solution would be to scroll the element at the top or bottom:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```